# Pattern or Format Match in XQuery MarkLogic

Tags: regex, xquery, marklogic

I am looking for given string, it has to be in `*(*)` format, `*` should not have space, no two words before `(`.

I am searching MarkLogic DB to see if given column value is in `[^\s]+\((?!\s)[^()]+(?<!\s)\)` format, if not replace it with this format.

I am still stuck at fetching data, and could not write the query to update

I am searching DB as

```
    let $query-opts := cts:search(doc(),
      cts:and-query((
        cts:directory-query(("/xyz/documentData/"),"1"),  
            cts:element-query( 
                xs:QName("cd:clause"),  (: <clause> element inside extended for checking query id :)
                cts:and-query((
                    cts:element-attribute-value-query( xs:QName("cd:clause"), xs:QName("tag"), "Title" ),  (: only if the <clause> is of type "Title" :)
                    cts:element-attribute-value-query( xs:QName("cd:xmetadata"), xs:QName("tag"), "Author")

                ))
             )
        ))
for $d in $query-opts
return (
     for $x in $d//cd:document/cd:clause/cd:xmetadata[fn:matches(@tag,"Author")]/cd:metadata_string
     where fn:matches($x/string(), "[^\s]+\((?!\s)[^()]+(?<!\s)\)")
       return 
       (   <documents> {
      <documentId> {$d//cd:cdf/cd:documentId/string()}</documentId>
     }</documents>
       )
     )
```

It's throwing up error invalid pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fn:matches`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#string.match) function does not support group modifiers like `(?!` and `(?<!`. Simplify your pattern, and capture false positives after the match with another match if necessary.

Doing an educated guess at what you are trying to do, I think you are looking for something like:

```
where fn:matches($x, '^.+\([^)]+\).*$') (: it uses parentheses :)
  and fn:not(fn:matches($x, '^[^\s]+\([^\s)]+\)$')) (: but does not comply to strict rules :)
```

HTH!

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thanks so much for your quick response. Its working. But failing on match values like xyz 123(123_xyz). There should not be space around parenthesis but it can be between words. I tried something like this [^-\s][\w\s*]+[^-\s]\([^\s][\w\s*]+[^\s]\), which is not working either. Any help is appreciated. It should not start with space and end with space also.

Comment: I'd recommend collecting two sets of values: one that are valid, and one that are invalid. Run isolated tests on those with a few regex attempts. I do notice that your regex in above comments doesn't have `\` before `(`, and the match value example you mention has an `_`, which is not captured by `\w` if I am not mistaken.