# Scalability of Regular Expressions (MarkLogic)

Tags: regex, marklogic

I have been looking around for ways to do regular expression in MarkLogic for XQuery and SPARQL. But it seems that for XQuery `fn:match` is the only way to approach this. It also seems that it is recommended to scale down the data with queries before running it through a for loop which can be seen in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399104/pattern-or-format-match-in-xquery-marklogic?rq=1). However, what If I am unable to scale it down and there is a need to loop through millions of data, is there a more scalable way to do this? I'm unsure if task bot is the  option I should be looking at.

On the other hand in SPARQL there are two ways to approach this.

First Method

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {?s ?p ?o
  FILTER (regex (?o, ".*Name.*", "i"))
}
```

Second Method

```
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {?s ?p ?o
  FILTER (fn:matches(?o, ".*Name.*"))
}
```

Among these two options to take in SPARQL are they the same or one of them is slightly better then the other? I would also greatly appreciate any advise or better ways to approach this for both SPARQL and XQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're doing a substring match with your search string as `"Name"`, and for that [fn:contains](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:contains) will suffice

```
fn:contains(?o, "Name")
```

Some advice:

> Avoid regex if you can by replacing with simple string search filters

I've once had to redo an entire project in Java making use of not so complex regex, but even those few lookarounds made it very slow. I had to break those regex into multiple levels of string search filters, and boy what difference that made. In MarkLogic, functions like [fn:substring-before](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:substring-before) and [fn:substring-after](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:substring-after) can help you in reducing the text length as you go through your levels of string search filters.

Still, if you have to use regex and are stuck with performance issues, then besides parallel computing, it's best to delegate the responsibility of the regex matching to a language / technology like Perl who is best at it.