# Using Thesaurus with SPARQL (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am currently trying to see if Thesaurus can be used in SPARQL from the XQuery Console. The code I am currently using is shown below

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";
import module namespace thsr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus" 
                             at "/MarkLogic/thesaurus.xqy";
sem:sparql(
'
PREFIX xs: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX cts: <http://marklogic.com/cts#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema/>
PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns>
PREFIX xdmp: <http://marklogic.com/xdmp#>

SELECT *
WHERE{
?question </has_comment> ?comment .
?commented_by_person </commented_by> ?comment .
#FILTER (cts:contains(fn:doc(?comment), thsr:expand( cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("text"),"go"), thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/wordnet.xml", "go"), (), (), () ) ) ) .

}',
(),
(),
() #thsr:expand( cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("text"),"go"), thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/wordnet.xml", "go"), (), (), () )
)
```

In the code shown above there are two locations with comments showing where I believe they could be placed. However, if `thsr:expand` is used before the SPARQL query it will remove all the `sem:triple` documents resulting in a empty query. On the other hand, if it is placed inside the SPARQL query, it will result in an error as the prefix for `thsr` is not provided, as I cant seem to find the prefix for `thsr` in SPARQL.

Therefore, any advise or ways to approach this will be greatly appreciated.

===Update===

For now I managed to make a solution based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399104/pattern-or-format-match-in-xquery-marklogic?rq=1). Where FLOWER Expression is used to iterate and check if a certain condition is fulfilled before returning the results. The codes to accomplish this can be seen below.

```
for $d in $test
return (
for $x in $d
 where(cts:contains($x["comment_text"],thsr:expand(cts:word-query("go"), thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/wordnet.xml", "go"),(), (), () ))) or ($x["comment_text"] = "comment_text")
 return $x
)
```

However, as seen the way it is done do not seem to be very scalable. Therefore, any improvements on this solution or other ways to accomplish this would be appreciated.